# How can I calculate the number of occurrences that is followed by a specific value? (add if statement)

Tags: bash, shell, awk

How can I calculate the number of occurrences that are ONLY followed by a specific value that is after E*? e.g:'EXXXX' ?

file.txt:

```
E2dd,Rv0761,Rv1408  
2s32,Rv0761,Rv1862,Rv3086  
6r87,Rv0761
Rv2fd90c,Rv1408
Esf62,Rv0761
Evsf62,Rv3086
```

i tried
input:

```
awk -F, '{map[$2]++} END { for (key in map) { print key, map[key] } }' file.txt
```

and add:

```
if [[ $line2 == `E*` ]];then
```

but not working, have syntax error

Expected Output:

```
total no of occurrences: 
Rv0761: 2
Rv3086:1
```

Now i can only count all number of occurrences of the second value

Comment: This might help. A regex to match all lines starting with `E` and then print second column: `awk 'BEGIN{ FS="," } /^E/{ print $2 }' file`

Comment: i still dun understand how to do sorry:((( i am a beginner O^O

Answer (score 0):

```
if [[ $line2 == `E*` ]];then
```

This definitely is not legal GNU `AWK` if statement, consult [If Statement](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/If-Statement.html) to find what is allowed, though it is not required in this case as you might as follows, let `file.txt` content be

```
E2dd,Rv0761,Rv1408  
2s32,Rv0761,Rv1862,Rv3086  
6r87,Rv0761
Rv2fd90c,Rv1408
Esf62,Rv0761
Evsf62,Rv3086
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}($1~/^E/){map[$2]++} END { for (key in map) { print key, map[key] } }' file.txt
```

gives output

```
Rv3086 1
Rv0761 2
```

Explanation: actions (enclosed in `{`...`}`) could be preceeded by pattern, which does restrict their execution to lines which does match pattern (in other words: condition does hold) in above example pattern is `$1~/^E/` which means 1st column does starts with `E`.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 0):

You are so close. You are only missing the REGEX to identify records beginning with `'E'` and then a `":"` concatenated on output to produce your desired results (not in sort-order). For example you can do:

```bash
awk -F, '/^E/{map[$2]++} END { for (key in map) { print key ":", map[key] } }' file.txt
```

**Example Output**

With your data in `file.txt` you would get:

```
Rv3086: 1
Rv0761: 2
```

If you need the output sorted in some way, just pipe the output of the `awk` command to `sort` with whatever option you need.